# Blanking on Python Data structure to use

Tags: python

I'm blanking on which python data structure to use here...

I query a database and get a list of names, then I go through again and get a count associated with each of those names. What's the easiest way for me to store that information in one place? I want something like a list with the name and its associated count. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) would do the job nicely. If you want just a basic data structure, a `dict` would serve your purpose as well.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you mean, you should be needing a dictionary.
Create an empty dictionary at first, then loop through your database; inside your loop, assign a field(name in your case) to your count(which I don't know)

```
myDictionary = {}
#Put your loop here
myDictionary = {Database.name: count}
#end your loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use a dictionary mapping names to count values? For example:

```
>>> dc = {'alice': 24, 'bob': 3, 'tim': 12}
>>> dc['bob']
3
```